# Update query that will set specific columns in a record with values from another record of same table

Tags: sql, oracle

look at this query;

```
update user_data set old_status= 'SNNNNS',
                     user_group='15',
                     default_rate='DEFAULT',
                     entity_num='1001'
where user_name='Dasu';
```

I know I could write the query like that and get result, but I dont want to be writing the values. These values are from another record with user_name 'sys' in the same table. I want a query that will update these particular columns in 'Dasu' with values from 'sys'.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, you can use `merge` with a self-join.  Alternatively, you can write correlated subqueries in the `update`:

```
update user_data
    set (old_status, user_group, default_rate, entity_num) = (select old_status, user_group, default_rate, entity_num from user_data where user_name = 'sys')
where user_name='Dasu';
```

Comment: hope you don't mind, but I updated your query to use a single correlated sub-query rather than one per column

Comment: @ninesided . . . That's fine.  I regularly forget which databases support this and which don't.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest a select in your update statement. For Example:

```
UPDATE Dasu
SET old_status = (SELECT old_status FROM sys WHERE Id = 1)
```